# How to make rounded collection cells fit on all screens?

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

So I'm normally use to making square sized collection view cells fit perfectly on all screens. However once I start adding spacing and section insets I run into this problem.  I am also using the storyboard.

This is how I would like all of the cells to look on each screen.

**iphoneX**

I have the minimum space for cells and lines at 10.
And for the right and left section insets they're set to 10 too.

[image]

This is the result I get on other devices **( iPhone 7/XsMax)**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set cell size programmatically by implementing `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize` method which is in `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol.

In this method you can set collection view cell's width 
`(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width/2)-10`

Comment: Im missing ```return CGSize``` I tired adding that code you provided to me in the return but it didn't work. Am I missing anything else mate?